# TypeError: User is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I have created a db.js file with the following code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

  var db = mongoose.connection; 

db.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('No connection found', err);

});

db.once('open', function(){
console.log('Connected');
})
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userEmails = new Schema({
name : String,
country : String,
email : String,
age: Number
});

userEmails.methods.checkName = function(){
   return this.model('User').age > 50 ? true : false
}



 module.export = mongoose.model('User', userEmails);
```

in my app.js file I have the following code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var User = require('./js/model/db');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("Hello World");
})
var Charles = new User({
   name: 'Charles',
   country: 'Nigeria',
   email: 'c.charlesworld@gmail.com',
   age: 99

 });

 Charles.save(function (err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Saved: ", data)
 });


app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('Application loaded at 3000...');
})
```

When i run node app.js I get the following error

[image]

is there something i am doing wrong and why is User not a function.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `module.exports` not `module.export`. Change that and it should work.

Comment: damn!...how didn't i see that...thanks.